# Connecting to SQL Server 2008 R2 database from Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, visual-studio-2013

I know it is a classic problem. But I am fed up. I am trying to generate a Windows Forms application in VS 2013. For database I use SQL Server 2008 R2. The database and application are on the same system. And I use the following connection string in my `app.config` file

```
<connectionStrings>
<add  name="Connectionstring1" 
      connectionString="Data Source=PC02;Initial Catalog=KCPIMSTest;
      User ID=sa;Password=***********;Integrated Security=true"  
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
 </connectionStrings>
```

I got this connection string by adding the database to server explorer of VS 2013 and take it from properties. But while running the application I get an exception on `con.open();`:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Cannot open database "KCPIMSTest" requested by the login. The login failed.

Instead of `Data Source=PC02`, I already tried `localhost`, `sqlexpress` and all.

These are the additional codes

```
  public void Save(string uname, string pwd)
  {
        string constring = getConnection();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring);

        if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            con.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("tblTest", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", uname);
        cmd.Parameters["@UserName"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        .....

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

        MessageBox.Show("Data Inserted Succesfully");
    }

    public static string getConnection()
    {
        /*Reading Connection string from App.config File */
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connectionstring1"].ConnectionString;
        return constr;
    }
```

Comment: Can you access the database from Server explorer? If yes, are the credentials in your connection string, the same as your windows login credentials?

Comment: Did you intentionally omit the password (i.e. masked it with asterisks), or did you just copy it from server explorer like what @smilu said?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using a SQL server login, and assuming you have the correct password, remove `Integrated Security=true` from your connection string.

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms254500(v=vs.80).aspx

P.S. Practice using `using` where possible (i.e. classes that implement `IDisposable` such as `SqlConnection`).

Comment: then i got the exception like An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Login failed for user 'sa'.

Comment: @Parvathiiiii your `sa` password is then wrong. Can you try a different user with the appropriate credentials?

Answer (score 1):

You should provide:

- either `User ID` and `Password` (when you use SQL Server login)
- or set `Integrated Security=true` (when you use Windows login).

Don't use both at the same time.

Comment: i change connectionString="Data Source=PC02;Initial Catalog=KCPIMSTest;Integrated Security=true" but got the exception like An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Cannot open database "KCPIMSTest" requested by the login. The login failed.

Comment: Do you have a Windows login in your SQL Server that corresponds to the user that is running your code?

Answer (score 1):

```
Data Source=PC02;Initial Catalog=KCPIMSTest;
      User ID=sa;Password=***********
```

Remove  `Integrated Security`. Then change your `password=*****` to `password=youroriginalpasswordtext` Then your login will work and

I think you copied this `connection string` from the `ServerExplorer`. The passwords will be `Masked` by default. So you should change the Mask to `original Password` itself.